# "Не ознакомленный" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

> Работник, не ознакомленный с приказом, считается не имеющим дисциплинарного взыскания.

"Не ознакомленный" - слитно или раздельно? Изначально склонялась в сторону слитного написания, поскольку здесь нет зависимых слов, но есть сомнения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отличительной особенностью  причастия "ознакомленный"  состоит в том, что оно ВСЕГДА имеет при себе зависимое слово и поэтому ВСЕГДА пишется с НЕ раздельно (без учета выражений разговорного характера): ознакомленный с приказом - не (ознакомленный с приказом).

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ: ОЗНАКОМИТЬ,  кого (что) с чем. Соответственно, ознакомленный  (с чем).

Comment: Почему же так категорично, София? Не всегда и не везде мы вставляем в свою русскую (письменную или разговорную) речь всякие зависимые слова. Иногда говорим и пишем коротко. Из одного причастия *неознакомленный* делать малопонятное исключение... овчина выделки не стоит, по-моему. Неужели есть академический отзыв? Приведите ссылку, пожалуйста!
Давайте возьмем причастие *победивший* (кого? что?) и состряпаем из него такое же исключение. Или причастие *заинтересовавший* (кого? что?). А потом найдем еще 100500 примеров. А потом - мильон...

Comment: Ознакомить - это не какой-то глагол-исключение, а просто глагол с двойным управлением, и это указывается в словаре: знакомить (ознакомить) кого (что) с чем. Таким образом, глагол требует обязательного наличия прямого дополнения, а также  существительного в форме Т.п. с предлогом С. А глагол победить требует только прямого дополнения (кого/что). Отсюда: ознакомить с приказом - ознакомленный с приказом, то есть нет одиночного причастия "ознакомленный"

Comment: >П. А. Флоренский. Имена (1926)  
Знаток какой-нибудь дисциплины отличается от поверхностно ознакомленного вовсе не суммою сведений, передаваемых аналитически, а глубоким вживанием в конкретные формы данной научной области, в силу какового он усматривает их, не делая попыток на аналитическое выделение отдельных признаков.

Comment: Неполная конструкция, сущ. в Т.п. подразумевается: "Знаток какой-нибудь дисциплины отличается От поверхностно ознакомленного (с данной дисциплиной)...".

Comment: Что же нам мешает в неполных конструкциях использовать причастие *неознакомленный*? Ничего не мешает...  
Мы и в совершенно полной конструкции прекрасно обойдем словарные "запреты" :  
>Режиссер Кристоф Ганс и сценарист Роджер Эвери с командой создали не просто кино, не просто экранизировали культовую игру, — они помогли истории обрести форму, чтобы с ней ознакомились все, будь то уже **человек в теме или неознакомленный синефил**. Браво! (сетевой коммент)

Так что гораздо проще применить в нашем сабже простое правило о присутствии/неприсутствии зависимого слова.

Comment: Да, этот пример мне нравится. Конечно, очень частный случай, но выразительный. Здесь раздельное написание невозможно, так как слово "неознакомленный" применяется в утвердительной конструкции в роли определения (отрицания  нет).

Answer (score 3):

*Работник, не ознакомленный с приказом...*
У причастия *не ознакомленный* имеется **зависимое слово** :  *с приказом*. Таким образом, написание НЕ с причастием - раздельное.

Answer (score 2):

Работник, не ознакомленный с приказом, считается не имеющим дисциплинарного взыскания. В этом предложении на виду причастный оборот. Пишется раздельно, так как причастие прошедшего времени имеет зависимое слово и вместе образуют оборот и обособляются.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказал, что слова "неознакомленный" нет вообще. Так же, как лет 30 назад не было слов "неслучайный" и "неслучайно" – всегда писалось раздельно. Кстати, в словаре трудностей Розенталя стоит только "не случайно", хотя сейчас пишут слитно почем зря.

Comment: Ваше замечание в принципе верно, но исключения всегда найдутся. Зависимое слово при *неознакомленном* можно легко опустить :  
*Неознакомленных новичков в сектор А не допускать!*

Answer (score 0):

> Изначально склонялась в сторону слитного написания, поскольку здесь нет зависимых слов, но есть сомнения

Как же нет, когда оно есть? Не ознакомленный с чем? с приказом.